# How to allow inactive user to login?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use a custom user model(AbstractBaseUser). How to allow inactive user to login?.  Model fields are email , active, admin,.....
By default active= false. For email confirmation activation. But I want to allow user to login both with active= true or false.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to keep the is active functionality and set the default value to `True` and create migration which will update value for currently inactive users. By following such approach you still have is active functionality, which may serve you in the moment when you will have to deactivate user.

To keep tracking on email confirmation just introduce new field `is_email_confirmed` and update the view which handles click on email to set that field to true.

Comment: So should I add another field email_ confirm (Boolean) to check email confirmation ?

Answer (score 2):

try add this in settings.py

`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend', )`

docs in this [User.is_active](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active)

Comment: . In this case, you’ll also want to customize the AuthenticationForm used by the LoginView as it rejects inactive users. Be aware that the permission-checking methods such as has_perm() and the authentication in the Django admin all return False for inactive users.??